# jest mockReturnValueOnce is not a function

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a custom hook that returns true or false by checking if the view is a mobile or a desktop view.

I'm trying to write a test for a page that uses this hook. I tried as following

```
import { useIsMobile } from '../../../../hooks/useIsMobile';

    jest.mock('../../../../hooks/useIsMobile');
    
    describe('Form', () => {
      beforeEach(jest.resetAllMocks);
    
      it('should render the correct header style for deliver to label in desktop view', () => {
    
        (useIsMobile as jest.Mock).mockReturnValueOnce(false);
        const delivery_label = screen.getByTestId('label1');
        expect(delivery_label.tagName).toEqual('H3');
      });
      it('should render the correct header style for deliver to label in mobile view', () => {
    
        (useIsMobile as jest.Mock).mockReturnValueOnce(true);
        const delivery_label = screen.getByTestId('label1');
        expect(delivery_label.tagName).toEqual('H4');
      });
    }
```

But I'm getting this error

```
TypeError: _useIsMobile.useIsMobile.mockReturnValueOnce is not a function
```

What does this mean and how can i fix this?

Comment: Are you sure about "../" in both import and mock? They are different.